# Wizard's bad habit

Tags: wizards, the-sword-of-truth

In the first two books, the wizards were described as truly awesome, though most of their deeds were off screen.

And then, they all had a bad habit of dying stupidly by physical damage.

The first time Kahlan met one in the Imperial Order (2nd book), she ran him through with a lance while he drunkenly trying to burn her with his fire. (wait, was he drunk? I don't remember)

The one waiting for her when she'd just escaped prison (2nd book) was throwing crazy lightning and was killed by an arrow from so freaking far away.

Then there's one shooting lightning at Scarlet when Richard charging to the Garden of Life (2nd book), too, dead by arrow.

Those in example were all power drunk (with Subtractive Magic) but I don't think they're stupid at all. Because, stupid wizard? No. Wizard is not stupid. They could be deceived in subtle ways, but they're not plain idiots.

Earlier in the book, we saw some girls in the Place of Prophet use condensed air as force field and it worked pretty well. So, such a thing existed. Maintaining multiple spells, too, is possible (the unnamed Dark sister bind the pretty girl, defend herself and conjure fires at the same time).

My question is, why is it none of the wizards ever thought of protecting himself before trying to fry his enemy?

Comment: If you fry your enemy correctly he doesn't get to retaliate. Perhaps the biggest weakness of wizards is their hubris, their ability to believe they are so powerful, they don't have to pay attention to the details. They certainly wouldn't be the first powerful people felled by something innocuous. See: Balder of Norse mythology.

Comment: Wizard's First Rule: People are stupid. That's literally the point of the first book.

Comment: Zedd is the only wizard with any intelligence in that series.

Comment: Several questions in one, for each of these wizards (most of them are characters of secondary importance), they could have specific reasons for such behavior and it may be not appropriate to generalize.